# Google SERP penalty for Multiple Business websites on one server?

Tags: seo, google, search-results, bing, penalty

I have tried to Google the answer to my question and Bing'ed my head against my desk after not being able to find a clear answer. This could have something to do with me lacking in not being able to define a clear enough query for the big G  and little B to answer. So maybe someone on ProWebmasters is willing to answer my question and help me out big time.

What I would like to know is if there are any (possible) negative affects/repercussions from Google and/or Bing for having multiple websites, all related to the same business-type, on one server and all of them sharing the same IP address.

On the server their will be a x number of websites from plumbers/blumbing businesses. All of them are totaly separate and legal business entities with completley separate owners. All of the websites will have the individual business address, phone number and other contact methods cleary displayed on the individual sites.

For Local SEO/SERP purposes the individual business information, location, business hours, Google+ and other social media channel will be defined in the json-ld format, ready for consumtion by G&B and everybody else that is interested. The only shared commonality (that I can think off) is that the businesses could be located in the same region and/or city.

Their will be no "duplicate" or "shared" content on any of the websites and there is absolutely no need to have any particular website "rank" higher then all of the others. This is not a noob link carousel building thingy.

G&B will only find a link in the footer off the different websites that  points to my own business website. This link will be of the "nofollow" type, I am not trying to rank my own site at the expense of my customers.

From all of the above I am inclined to think that their could be no negative affect in the natural ranking of any of the websites, but I would like to know for sure if my assumption is correct.

If anyone reading this would like to know some additional information before giving a difinitve yes or no answer, let me know!

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What you are describing is done all day everyday. No worries.

Comment: what @clostenoc said...
i'll just add that Google has been discounting footer webmaster links from SERPs for quite a while, irrespective of whether they are nofollow

Answer (score 2):

absolutely no penalty for "multiple websites, all related to the same business-type, on one server and all of them sharing the same IP address". Different if these multiple website are low quality website that all link to another website. If the websites are just few simple pages build to get some back links you will eventually incur in penalty independently if the website are in the same server or one in England and one in Antarctica. Instead, if you have quality websites, full of content, even 20, that all link to another website of yours, the links will be good links as came from good websites. Easy, natural! No tricks. Is not where the server is located that can generate penalty but the quality of the website where the links come from. Even if from the same owner. If somebody has the capacity to create many good quality website well... it will be consider an authority and the last things is to try to hide it (again even if you have Antarctica and north pole servers Google will know are yours...). Avoid anyway back links from low quality website.
I think here you can find a nice evidence of what I wrote: [Backlinks from same IP class](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/webmasters/ZUtgNFzg5T4;context-place=topicsearchin/webmasters/C$20class$20IP)

Answer (score 1):

You just described Shared Hosting. For example, for some of my smaller sites, I use a shared hosting plan (because that's really all they require)..just out of curiosity - I decided to look into how many websites were hosted on that server by running a reverse IP lookup.

The result? 518 Different websites - as in 518 Different companies with 518 Different registrations, addresses, and phone numbers - some of them remarkably similar sounding in terms of industry and some completely different, some downright silly..

And my the two smaller sites that I was referring to (both less than a month old) are already quickly growing and starting to rank in the top 10 for a handful of keywords even though quite honestly i didn't do as much as I could have for them because I've been too busy with clients lol.

So to answer your question, no. no penalty